# angularjs directive datepicker jquery year range

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I am using in my angular application jquery datepicker for a field date of birth, and I need to navigate between year range, but every time I select one year remaining years in the select, ie I have set to -50 years and appear-10years,  and when I select 1993 after subtracting 50 years and left in 1943.

my directive:

```
DeelezApp.directive('datepicker', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require : 'ngModel',
    link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        $(function(){
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "c-50:c-10",
                onSelect:function (date) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
}   });
```

as I can do for the year range does not change then select a year?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

just change this line

`yearRange: "c-50:c-10"`

to

```
yearRange: "-50:-10"
```

Thanks